# assignment and reference initialization from a temporary

Tags: c++, reference, initialization, temporary-objects

suppose i have the following:

```
boost::unordered_map< string , someValueType > map;
someValueType& value = map[ "key" ] = someValueType();
```

the last line contains:

- a temporary constructed instance of `someValueType`
- an assignment of the temporary into a new map entry
- initialization of a reference to the map entry

so if next line is:

```
   value.someProperty = 42;
```

this will try to change the map entry right? not the original temporary?

I know in this case if the reference couldn't take a temporary because it is non const (so a compiler error or the absence of one would answer my question), but if i added the const to the reference declaration, i'm not sure what the evaluation rules would say in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's true. You have an initialization with an assignment expression on the right:

```
someValueType & value = (map["key"] = someValueType());
```

In fact, this is equivalent to:

```
someValueType & value = map["key"];
```

This is because the `[]`-operator creates a new element if one doesn't already exist for that key.

Binding the map entry to a const reference makes no difference. However, if you know that the key is guaranteed to exist, then you can bind a const reference to the mapped value even if you only have a constant reference to the map itself:

```
void (MapType const & m)
{
    someValueType const & = m.find("key")->second;
}
```

This would be an error of course if the key didn't exist, since you'd be dereferencing the end iterator.

Comment: thanks Kerrek, is there a way to create a new element in the map without the temporary? something like emplace initialization?

Comment: @lurscher: [Yes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace), but no compiler I know of supports it yet. (All associative containers have `emplace` in the new standard.)

Comment: @Irfy: I just meant that I don't know any compiler+library which implements associative-map emplacement at this point. It's in the standard, so it's bound to come, but practically it's not widespread yet.

Comment: @Kerrek : I believe VC++11 Beta implements emplacement (though with kludged variadic templates, obviously).